# Future Builder malfunctioning in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i was writing my future builder like this

```
 FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (c, s) =>
        s.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            :  nextPage()
```

ALthough working fine, but it was showing an error for couple of seconds which said "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' is thrown my futureBuilder. "
next i changed it to

```
    FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((response) {
    nextPage();    
  }),  
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return null;
    } else if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

but here the issue is my nextpage() just flashes and vanishes away.

any help?

**EDIT:**
here is my full code, and my requirement is a circularprogressindicator for first 3 seconds,and then nextpage().

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App());
}
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {









  nextPage() async{

    bool visitedFlag = await getVIsitingFlag();
    setVIsitingFlag();
    if (visitedFlag == true) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
    }
    else {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
    }
  }


@override
  void initState() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((response) {
    nextPage();
  });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF311a2e),
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
     CircularProgressIndicator();
    ),
    );
  }
}



 getVIsitingFlag() async{
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool alreadyVisited = preferences.getBool('alreadyVisited') ?? false ;
return alreadyVisited;
}

 setVIsitingFlag()async{
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
preferences.setBool('alreadyVisited', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to show any widget on completion of your future anyway, just remove the `FutureBuilder`. You only need it when you want to *build* something based on your future and you don't.

Call your method in your `initState` method:

```
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((response) {
    nextPage();    
  }
```

and build your page to look like a progress indicator, without the FutureBuilder.

Comment: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget', this i keep getting then.

Comment: That is not possible if you followed my answer. Did you really **remove** the FutureBuilder?

Comment: yes i did, let me edit my question, with full code.

Comment: Your child is not "nextPage", your child is the CircularProgressIndicator. Where is the `initState` method that I told you you should put your code in?

Comment: its not accepting Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3).... method in init state.

Comment: What do you mean by "accept"? Do you get errors? Please post your code and your errors.

Comment: the full line is underlined with red color.

Comment: Given that I cannot see the code, nor magically know what error it is that makes your IDE underline it in red, you need to be more precise. Please post your code and your errors.

Comment: thankyou so much,i took time to understand how you guided, but kudos to you, you were right.. thankyou once again